# Uploading multiple images to server causes error

Tags: php, android, post, android-async-http

I am using the Loopj AsyncHttpClient for Android and it works like a charm.
Now I am trying to upload three small images to my server, and I am having some problems. 
It is very weird because it works perfectly if I upload 2 images, but when I try to add a third to the same request, the server response is the error 3 for file uploads:

```
UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL
Value: 3; The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.
```

So when I do this:

```
params.put("photo1", f1);
params.put("photo2", f2);
```

it works...but when I add a third:

```
params.put("photo1", f1);
params.put("photo2", f2);
params.put("photo3", f3);
```

the server fails to process the request...
I have checked the files, the server side app seems to work fine (I tried sending the data with postman and it works)

Do you know why AsyncHttpClient would fail uploading 3 files but succeed uploading 2??

thanx in advance

Comment: How do you get the files on your server side?

Comment: omg i had the exact thing happen to me! thanks so much for asking!

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been introduced with version 1.4.4 of this library. I did not have time to dig deeper yet, but I suspect this particular commit: https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/commit/9f73dc722fdf8b564bf1487eef395d0b7e4ae862 to be responsible for this issue.

As a workaround, use version 1.4.3 for now. It should work fine.

Comment: thanks so much for the response! i'll try this also, when i get to it! =D

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem after update to 1.4.4. If I upload 2 images, the server will only get 1 image (if 3, will get 2). After search and testing, I know the server, my code and 1.4.3 are ok.

Today I try this:

```
params.put("photo1", new FileInputStream(f1));
params.put("photo2", new FileInputStream(f2));
params.put("photo3", new FileInputStream(f3));
```

It works.